# Applying command from host machine to qemu-system-riscv64 on XV6-riscv

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, xv6

I am using [qemu-system-riscv6](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/RISCV) to test and develop on top of [XV6-riscv](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv) toy OS.

I am looking for a way to run the XV6-riscv OS with command line input from the host OS.

For example, I have a function called `my_function`. I want to type something like:

`make qemu --input "my_function"`

And that it will result in:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0

xv6 kernel is booting

hart 2 starting
hart 1 starting
init: starting sh
$ my_function
```

I have searched qemu-system-riscv6 documentation and couldn't find anything. Qemu is far too versatile, and I couldn't find anything on the qemu documentation as well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587561/how-to-send-commands-to-running-qemu-instance)  seems to complicated to embed inside the XV6 framework.

Is there any known method to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Inside xv6 operating system, you cannot run outside functions. That being said, you can only run commands which are available and can be seen when you boot the operating system. For example, `ls` command is available in xv6 OS. So you can do following to run the command directly from host:

```bash
echo "ls" | make qemu
```

This will list the directories immediately after booting inside xv6.